Unable to map rotations of an ellipse onto a different point
I wrote a program that creates an ellipse made of a series of points that can be rotated by an angle, psi, in the xy plane. I am using a rotation matrix to rotate the ellipse.
angle = linspace(0, Num_periods*2*pi, N_frames);

x1 = a1 * cos(angle);
y1 = b1 * sin(angle);

psi=pi/4;
R1 = [cos(psi), -sin(psi); sin(psi), cos(psi)];

ellipse1 = R1 * [x1; y1];

x1_rot = ellipse1(1, :) + x1_0;
y1_rot = ellipse1(2, :) + y1_0;

I am then attempting to add another point which should be located at a distance l_proj_1 from the center in the direction of the short axis, but it is located in different spots relative to the ellipse based on different angles. I also notice that the shape of the ellipse changes sometimes based on the rotation angle, which also should not happen. Is this an error in my code or Matlab and how do I fix either. Thank you.
phi_1 = pi/12; %angle of opening 
theta_1 = pi/4; %tilt angle
l_1 = a1/(sin(phi_1));
l_proj_1 = l_1*cos(phi_1)*cos(theta_1);

x0_base_1 = x1_0 + l_proj_1*cos(psi);
y0_base_1 = y1_0 + l_proj_1*sin(psi);

figure;
for i = 1:N_frames
    plot(x1_rot(i),y1_rot(i),'o')
    axis([0 nx 0 ny])
    hold on
    pause(.5)
    plot(x0_base_1,y0_base_1,'o')
end

I have tried altering the sin's and cos's of the bases and the negatives. It is never consistent.

I don't get any misalignment running your code, nor can I see anything wrong in the code itself. I can only recommend using axis equal in the plot, otherwise the ellipse axes will have the wrong orientation. (Actually, I realize now that if the axes have very different scales and the ellipse's center is far from the center of the plot, it may result in the ellipse itself appearing deformed). Can you please provide an example with all the missing constants that results in the ellipse having a wrong shape?

@kikon That seemed to work perfectly (with a change in the trig functions and signs to get it in the position I wanted). Thank you very much!
